# Hubbard model and orthogonality of the ground state

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, many-body, second-quantization

I'm currently learning the Hubbard model. Under the assumption of contact potential, the interaction Hamiltonian written in the second quantization is
\begin{equation}
H_{int} = U\sum_{i}\sum_{\lambda}\,c^\dagger_{i,\lambda}c_{i,\lambda}c^\dagger_{i,-\lambda}c_{i,-\lambda}
\end{equation}
Now I transfer it into $\pmb{k}$-space
\begin{equation}
H_{int} = \frac{U}{\Omega}\sum_{\pmb{k},\pmb{p},\pmb{q}}\sum_{\lambda}\,c^\dagger_{k+q,\lambda}c^\dagger_{p-q,-\lambda}c_{p,-\lambda}c_{k,\lambda}
\end{equation}
and try to compute the first order perturbation due to this interaction $\langle F|H_{int}|F\rangle$, where $|F\rangle$ is the ground state of the system. My questions are:

1. Can I argue that the only way to have non-zero matrix element is to let $\pmb{q} = 0$ (otherwise the matrix element becomes an inner product of two orthonormal states)?
2. If so, what if I insist the electrons interact via Coulomb interaction? Would the requirement $\pmb{q}\neq 0$ always makes $\langle F|H_{int}|F\rangle = 0$ (due to the orthogonality of the state after annihilating two electrons with different spins)?